# Angular 2 binding only refresh on Observable timer

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to learn angular 2 and I've a conflict between Observable and angular's binding.The result of my binding works but only refresh on the timer.

The timer is used in an header module to change title showed every 4 seconds based on an array :

header.component.js

```js
ngOnInit() {
  let timer = Observable.timer(4000,4000);
  timer.subscribe(t=>this.currentTitle=(this.currentTitle===this.headerTitle.length-1)?0:++this.currentTitle);
}
```

it runs as expected but when i create a second module with this template

calculator.component.html :

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" #value1/>
  <input type="text" #value2/>

  <p>{{value1.value*value2.value}}</p>
</div>
```

it works also but only every 4 seconds when the title change, why does observable timer affects my binding?

Comment: Can you make a demo on jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: I did not understand anything.